# laravel query builder from normal query

Tags: laravel-4

```
DB::select(DB::raw( 'SELECT a.bill_no, a.account_id, a.bill_date, a.amount_paid,
                                b.transaction_code,b.amount from  bill_det a left join
                                (select bill_no, transaction_code, sum(amount) as amount from payment_transactions 
                                where status = "success" group by bill_no ) b
                                on a.bill_no = b.bill_no where a.amount_paid != b.amount order by b.bill_no'));
```

this is normal query.change into laravel query?.
i tried.

```
$bill=DB::table('bill_det')->leftJoin('payment_transactions', 'bill_det.bill_no', '=', 'payment_transactions.bill_no')
                                ->select('bill_det.bill_no','bill_det.account_id','bill_det.bill_date','bill_det.amount_paid',
                                'payment_transactions.transaction_code',DB::raw('sum(payment_transactions.amount) as amount'))
                                ->where('payment_transactions.status','=','success')
                                ->where('sum(payment_transactions.amount)','!=',DB::raw('bill_det.amount_paid'))
                                ->groupBy('bill_det.bill_no')
                                ->orderBy('bill_det.bill_no','desc');
```

i can't compare   `-> where('sum(payment_transactions.amount)','!=',DB::raw('bill_det.amount_paid'))`

i used like this `->whereRaw('bill_det.amount_paid != sum(payment_transactions.amount)')`

> {"error":{"type":"Illuminate\Database\QueryException","message":"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as row_count from `bill_det` left join `payment_transactions` on `bill_det`.`bill_no` = `payment_transactions`.`bill_no` where `payment_transactions`.`status` = success and bill_det.amount_paid != sum(payment_transactions.amount) group by `bill_det`.`bill_no` order by `bill_det`.`bill_no` desc) count_row_table)"

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: i tried. the issue is i can't able to compare sum amount in where

Comment: You need to use whereRaw to compare sum() results.

Comment: i used whereRaw but it gave error like above.

Comment: I think you should use "having" statement instead of using "where" statement

Comment: i have to sum one table amount depands upon bill no  which compare to another table which is having constant amount that is bill amount total amount for every single customers

Comment: i tried.havingRaw working  thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::select(DB::raw( 'SELECT a.bill_no, a.account_id, a.bill_date, a.amount_paid,
                            b.transaction_code,b.amount from  bill_det a left join
                            (select bill_no, transaction_code, sum(amount) as amount from payment_transactions 
                            where status = "success" group by bill_no ) b
                            on a.bill_no = b.bill_no where a.amount_paid != b.amount order by b.bill_no'));
```

After converting this to laravel Query::

```
$query = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('bill_det')
            ->select('a.bill_no', 'a.account_id', 'a.bill_date', 'a.amount_paid', 'b.transaction_code', 'b.amount')
            ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(select bill_no, transaction_code, sum(amount) as amount from payment_transactions 
                            where status = "success" group by bill_no) b'), function($join) {
                $join->on('a.bill_no', '=', 'b.bill_no');
            })
            ->where('a.amount_paid','<>', 'b.amount')
             ->orderBy('b.bill_no')
            ->get();
```

In case you want to know how to use raw expression inside where then use this:

```
$query->whereRaw(DB::raw('(your expression!!)'));
```